# 405 error when POSTing to ASMX using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, post, asmx, http-status-code-405

[image: 405 Error]

[Site is here.](http://bit.ly/1ajj5AE)

Things we have tried:

- ProtocolSupportModule has been updated to All verbs.
- DNS is externally visible.
- Anonymous Authentication is enabled.
- Headers added:

  <customHeaders>
              <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
              <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://s-alg.cengage .com" />
              <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-PINGOTHER" />
              <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS, HEAD" />
              <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1000" />
          </customHeaders>

I’m not sure what to try next. Hopefully is something to do with Web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method has to be decorated with [WebInvoke] to enable POST method.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
```

**Update:**

If it is asmx, include the below protocols in web.config

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

in system.web

Also, decorate the web method with [scriptmethod] to be accessed from script

Comment: Should I enable "OPTIONS" as well? That's what seems to be getting sent.

Comment: Is that a cross origin request? if not , i dont think options has to be enabled. Also, your title says WCF where as the screenshot shows ASMX.. is it asmx?

Comment: ooops, guess its asmx. and yes, it is cross origin.