# 405 (Method Not Allowed), Using JQuery and Ajax in a Web App

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I have a little problem with my project, I can't add a user in my database table named user, when i debug the code it returns `405 (Method Not Allowed)`, my webservices work but when I click on the button in my html page i can't do anything. Sorry if my comments are bad i'm new in this technology. I'm using VS 2017 and I added the HTTP protocols.

The script from the HTML page :

```
function sendUser() {
    $.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           URL: "./WebService.asmx/Subscribe",
           data: { 'username': $("#user").val() }
     });
}

function userOK() {
    alert("data");
}

function userKO() {}

function addEvents() {
    $("#btnSendUser").click(sendUser);
}

$(function () {
       addEvents();
});
```

The webMethod from the webService

```
    [WebMethod]
    public int Subscribe(string username)
    {

        int result = 0;
        //connection to the db 
        string cnxString = @"Data Source=myServerAdress;Initial Catalog=myDB;User ID=myUser;Password=myPass";
        //open and close the connection after the execution
        using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(cnxString))
        {
            try
            {
                cnx.Open();
                //create a command with a query and the parameter typed in a form
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"INSERT INTO [User] (name) VALUES ('{username}')");
                //set the connection 
                cmd.Connection = cnx;
                //return the row affected as a string 
                result = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new HttpException("error cnx");
            }

        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `GET` method? Any Cross-Origin errors?

Comment: Yes i tried, GET works

Comment: Ok. Check this answer, it might be helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19597289/4453058

Comment: Where do i have to put the line ? It just displays many errors and i don't know how to solve it

Comment: Sorry man. Unable to help now. Tag `asp.net`,`asmx` to get the attention.